# How can I prompt midjourney to generate images of D&D weapons other than swords?

Tags: prompt-design, image-generation, text-to-image, midjourney

I'm trying to generate some cool magical weapons for my D&D campaign using midjourney, but I'm having a real struggle getting it to do things other than swords.

I couldn't get it to do a bow at all, and it really seems to struggle with warhammers, axes, spears, maces, etc, often creating crazy contorted versions of the real weapons or simply ignoring the request entirely.

Some examples of prompts I've tried that failed completely:

> A bow leans against a wooden wall. Tight focus, closeup. Bright
> lighting. Silver color scheme. Fantasy, d&d, oil painting --no faces

> A sharp-pointed spear. Melee weapon, polearm. Tight focus, closeup.
> Fantasy, d&d, oil painting --no faces

> A black serrated war axe inscribed with runes being held in one hand
> by a warrior. Tight focus, closeup. Background is a cavern. Bright
> lighting. Fantasy, d&d, oil painting --no faces

Anyone have some prompt suggestions to reliably produce these?